# Problems aligning one figure with four texts

Tags: beamer, paragraphs

Basically, this is the problem:

[image]

When I use `\begin{tabular}` with four columns cells are not well aligned, and also I have to write parts of the paragraph in individual rows, not really the best approach afaik. I tried columns but this also seems to be a complex approach. Here an image with both ways:

tabular:

[image]

columns (I just used the same above text for simplicity):

[image]

and the MWE:

```
\documentclass[compress,final]{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent=25}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\usepackage{ragged2e}       % for justifying

\begin{document}

\section{ITEM}
\subsection{item}
\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip, width=1.0\textwidth]{1fig.png}
    \vspace{.25cm}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2.75cm}|p{2.35cm}|p{2.35cm}|p{2.35cm}|}
        \hline
        text starts here but it has     &   text starts here but it has     &   text starts here but it has     &   text starts here but it has \\
        \hline
        to continue in the next line    &   to continue in the next line    &   to continue in the next line    &   to continue in the next line \\
        \hline
        because this is a table with    &   because this is a table with &  because this is a table with    &   because this is a table with    \\
        \hline
        rows, and writing things like   &   rows, and writing things like   &   rows, and writing things like   &   rows, and writing things like   \\
        \hline
        this is pretty crazy!!          &   this is pretty crazy!!          &   this is pretty crazy!!          &   this is pretty crazy!!  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip, width=1.0\textwidth]{1fig.png}
    \vspace{.25cm}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \justifying
            text starts here but it has to continue in the next line because this is a table with rows, and writing things like this is pretty crazy!!
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.175\textwidth}
            \justifying
            text starts here but it has to continue in the next line because this is a table with rows, and writing things like this is pretty crazy!!
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.15\textwidth}
            \justifying
            text starts here but it has to continue in the next line because this is a table with rows, and writing things like this is pretty crazy!!
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \justifying
            text starts here but it has to continue in the next line because this is a table with rows, and writing things like this is pretty crazy!!
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I also attach here the `1fig.png` for testing.

[image]

So, I think columns should give better results, but not sure how. Is there a simple way to get this, something like individual paragraphs for each part of the whole figure (it's only 1 figure)?

Thanks in advance for any pointers on this,

Comment: With only fragments of disconnected code it is very hard to see what you tried or what the problems are. with `\begin{tabular}{p{2.75cm}p{2.35cm}p{2.35cm}p{2.35cm}}` for example why are the cells not aligned and why do you have to enter paragraphs in single lines? It always helps if you post complete small documents.

Comment: If `columns` or a `tabular` is not ideal nor the best approach, I'm pretty sure everything else will be far more difficult.

Comment: Thank you David and Werner for your answers, I updated my post with the mwe, images and more explanations. I think I'm getting closer, but the texts have to be aligned with the images (ie. 1 subimage to the left, and 3 subimages to the right), so taking into account the blank space in between, it'd be great your suggestions and ideas, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility.  I stuck with your `columns` approach.  I can use multiple `columns` environments, one for each needed row (here, I show 2 such rows).  Within a single "`columns`", I make each `column` of the same width and add gaps between them by way of `\hspace`s as well as a blank `column`.

```
\documentclass[compress,final]{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent=25}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\usepackage{ragged2e}       % for justifying
\newcommand\mygap[1][.01]{\hspace{#1\textwidth}}
\begin{document}

\section{ITEM}
\subsection{item}
\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip, width=1.0\textwidth]{1fig}
    \vspace{.25cm}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]\mygap%
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \justifying
            text starts here but it has to continue 
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.11\textwidth}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \justifying
            text starts here 
        \end{column}\mygap%
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \justifying
            text starts here but it has to continue in the next
        \end{column}\mygap%
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \justifying
            text starts here but 
        \end{column}\mygap%
    \end{columns}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]\mygap%
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \justifying
            in the next line because this is a table with rows, and writing things like this is pretty crazy!!
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.11\textwidth}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \justifying
            but it has to continue in the next line because this is a table with rows, and writing things like this is pretty crazy!!
        \end{column}\mygap%
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \justifying
              line because this is a table with rows, and writing things like this is pretty crazy!! 
        \end{column}\mygap%
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \justifying
            it has to continue in the next line because this is a table with rows, and writing things like this is pretty crazy!!
        \end{column}\mygap%
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton Steven, it works nicely, `\mygap` really nice trick

Comment: One more question, could you please explain the structure of `\mygap`?

Comment: @Gery As you see from the definition, `\newcommand\mygap[1][.01]{\hspace{#1\textwidth}}`, the macro just invokes an `\hspace`, with a default value of `0.01\textwidth`.  However, you can invoke `\mygap[0.02]` and get the gap for that invocation changed to `0.02\textwidth`.  It follows the pattern of LaTeX *optional arguments*.

Comment: cool, thanks for that explanation, it is clear now, cheers